# How to upload code to the RP2040 Chip using a usb cable

Tags: usb

I am wondering how I would take my SMD raspberry Pi RP2040 Chip like for custom pcbs(because google doesn't understand the difference between the chip itself and the Pico with it) and upload my code onto it. My thought it that it would have my code on my computer and I would upload it using arduino IDE or Thonny and it would work.
Thanks